# Plotting Real Time Graph With Extra Data Points

Tags: c++, plot, graph, real-time

I want to plot Data that is received from RS232. But my problem is that I have extra data points and It's not adaptive with my pixel numbers so to show the graph real time and With no Delay I need to select some Data points and eliminate some other points Online. What algorithm can help me to do that simply and How I can write this program?
My programming language is C++.

Edit:
I don't want a prepared command. I want to write with myself. Suppose the data is an heart rate and you want to show that on your display Real-Time. if have the same data you can draw with setpixel at each time you received data but I have a lot of data that is received contentiously and You have to choose some of them.

Comment: You could use a `std::vector` as it is quite flexible regarding adding and deleting of data.

Comment: Without knowing what data should be kept and what should be eliminated, it's impossible for us to say anything. This question is way to broad anyway.

Comment: google re-sampling  or changing sampling rate. usually linear interpolation is used for such things. But for sensor dat aplots like this nearest neighbor is better so you can render more then 1 value to single time slot. that way you will not lose so much information ...